# PrimeFaces progress bar start event

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I want to provide a progress bar using Primefaces for a server side event. My first attempt was to include an **action** to the button that fires also the Ajax progress bar:

```
 <p:commandButton value="Start" type="button" action="#{userAction.doWork}"  onclick="PF('pbAjax').start();PF('startButton2').disable();" widgetVar="startButton2" />

 <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{userAction.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated" global="false">
       <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{userAction.onComplete}" update=":form" oncomplete="startButton2.enable()"/>
 </p:progressBar>
```

This does not work as the UserAction.doWork is not being called. So my second attempt was to provide an ajax event="start":

```
<p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{userAction.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated" global="false">
   <p:ajax event="start" listener="#{userAction.go}"  />
   <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{userAction.onComplete}" update=":form" oncomplete="startButton2.enable()"/>
 </p:progressBar>
```

This does not work either as I get a "  **Event:start is not supported**." 
Any suggestion to get called the userAction.go method ??

Answer (score 0):

Remove `type="button"` and it will work.

```
<p:commandButton value="Start" action="#{userAction.doWork}"  onclick="PF('pbAjax').start();PF('startButton2').disable();" widgetVar="startButton2" />
```